# Seeing apt-get changelogs for to-be-upgraded packages

Tags: apt

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14394/apt-changelog-for-to-be-installed-packages) describes how to get the changelog for a given package. However, it's the whole changelog.

What I'd like is a way to see what will be changed in whatever I'm about to upgrade. For example, I was imagining something like:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade --show-changelogs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  foo
    -- adds the bar feature for better snazziness
    -- removes the deprecated baz feature

1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,864 kB of archives.
After this operation, 285 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Unfortunately, I don't see anything like that in the man pages for apt-get. Does this or something similar exist?

**UPDATE:** I've written a [short blog post](http://jxf.me/entries/better-apt-ubuntu/) talking about apt-listchanges and Debian changelogs in a little more depth that incorporates some of the feedback in this question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The nearest thing to what you are looking for can be had with a package called `apt-listchanges`, which will give you a changelog summary when you upgrade packages. You can set it up so the changelog notes appear in the terminal directly after `apt-get` downloads the upgrade (see below explanation and screenshot), but before you install it.

You can install the program with

```
sudo apt-get install apt-listchanges
```

and then set it up with

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apt-listchanges
```

The setup file created is `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf`.

My setup has the changelog information being shown directly as text in the terminal (stdout), which is just what you wanted. I find this is better than having a pager load up the information. I just have changelogs selected in my conf file, so the news about the package is not shown. I have also set it up to email root the excerpt of the changelog. You need to set up local email by referencing [my article here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2261/how-are-administrators-supposed-to-read-roots-mail/209877#209877) if you want to use this feature.

This is my `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf`:

```
[apt]
frontend=text
email_address=root
confirm=1
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=changelogs
```

A screenshot of the upgrade procedure when `apt-listchanges` is installed. I have set it to ask me for install confirmation after reading the changelog excerpt.

[image]

For more information see `man apt-listchanges` and [the Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/apt-listchanges.1.html).

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks very much.

Comment: Doesn't work by me. Followed all the steps but still no description.

Comment: @ka3ak didn't work for me on 19.04 too. I opened https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-listchanges/+bug/1832687 about it.

Answer (score 17):

I use `aptitude`:

```
$ aptitude changelog package-name
```

See this question: [apt changelog for to-be installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14394/apt-changelog-for-to-be-installed-packages)

Comment: Is this the same link the OP posted when he said he had taken a look at it but wanted something different?

Comment: This is the whole changelog for a single package -- what I wanted was just the changes in all the packages I'm about to upgrade. Doing `aptitude changelog ...` and visually parsing out the results would be very tedious, especially when more than a few packages change.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ apt changelog firefox
```

Works for me. For external PPAs it fails, even though this one is at http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/binary/p/plasma-framework/5.67.0-0ubuntu2/changelog

```
$ apt changelog plasma-framework
E: Ophalen van changelog:/plasma-framework.changelog is mislukt  Logbestand met veranderingen niet beschikbaar voor plasma-framework=5.67.0-0ubuntu2~ubuntu19.10~ppa1
```

Or more useful, via Synaptic:

```
This change is not coming from a source that supports changelogs.

Failed to fetch the changelog for plasma-framework
URI was: http://ppa.launchpad.net/pool/main/p/plasma-framework/plasma-framework_5.67.0-0ubuntu2~ubuntu19.10~ppa1_amd64.changelog
```

Which doesn't work:

```
E: ERROR: couldn't open /root/.synaptic/synaptic.conf for writing - ofstream (5: Input/output error)
E: An error occurred while saving configurations.
```

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite: install *apt-listchanges*:

```
sudo apt install apt-listchanges
```

Then the following oneliner will show the *changelog diff* between currently-installed and to-be-upgraded packages:

```
(cd $(mktemp -d) && apt download $(apt list -qq --upgradable | cut -f1 -d"/") && apt-listchanges *.deb)
```

This oneliner will first download the latest versions of `.deb` archives of the to-be-upgraded packages to a temporary directory.
Then `apt-listchanges` is executed on these `*.deb` packages.

This onliner does not need admin/superuser/sudo rights.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
fullList=$(apt list --upgradable 2> /dev/null)
shortList=$(echo "${fullList}" | cut -f1 -d"/" | sed s/Listing...//)

for pkg in $shortList ; do
    echo "## ${pkg}"
    apt-get changelog ${pkg}
done
```

Press `q` to read the changelog for each package ; if you redirect the output of the pager to a file, it will loop through the list until the end, albeit slowly.