# How can I get persistent output from apt-listchanges without intervention?

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, apt-listchanges

I have [installed and configured](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272215/seeing-apt-get-changelogs-for-to-be-upgraded-packages) the [`apt-listchanges`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/apt-listchanges) package to display changelogs from updates.

Output of `cat /etc/apt/listchanges.conf` (configured according to [Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/stable/en/man1/apt-listchanges.1.html) for `apt-listchanges`):

```
[apt]
frontend=xterm-pager
email_address=
confirm=false
which=both
```

It's a bit difficult to test different configurations, because it relies on updates coming through. So far, however, no configuration results in an output that **remains on the screen after the update is complete**.

For example:

- if I choose the browser option and Firefox is already running, it fails
- if I choose the xterm or GTK window option, the new window appears, but disappears when the update is complete
- if I choose the option to display text in the same terminal, even without the option to confirm before applying, I must quit the display before the update continues
- if I use Update Manager rather than the command line, it never works and throws an error (although the update is applied)

How can I configure `apt-listchanges` and `apt upgrade` (or Update Manager) to:

- download and apply updates without interruption or intervention required (that is, no confirmation prompt from apt-listchanges)
- display the news/changelogs on the screen (same terminal, different terminal, GTK window, browser window, Update Manager, I don't mind, but not [email](http://askubuntu.com/questions/272215/seeing-apt-get-changelogs-for-to-be-upgraded-packages))
- have the display persist beyond the completion of the update

(As a last ditch attempt, output to a text file wouldn't be a terrible option.)

Comment: maybe try using `tee -a` as a pager?

Answer (score -1):

[**Read how to configure** `apt-listchanges`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/apt-listchanges.1.html)

---

**before upgrade**:

```
apt-get changelog <package name>
```

---

**after upgrade**:

To list all packages installed on the system, from a terminal prompt type (large output):

```
dpkg -l
```

To pipe the output through `grep` to see if a specific package is installed:

```
dpkg -l | grep <package name>
```

To list the files installed by a package:

```
dpkg -L <package name>
```

To identify which package was installed a file:

```
dpkg -S /somedir/some.file
```

---

Read more about [**dpkg**](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/dpkg.html) or `man dpkg`.

---

Comment: I thought what none limits to run `apt-get changelog <package name>` immediately before `apt update && apt upgrade`. Cause it is the same changes.

Comment: look updated about `apt-listchanges`

Comment: hey man )) what version of Ubuntu you are uses? 

Problem with your Update Manager resolvable by ONE clean update && upgrade (or dist-upgrade) from Terminal. Looks like you can not end session or forget to reboot ...

Comment: hi swift, I've removed my comments and focused the question on apt-listchanges - I'm definitely looking for a configuration-based answer here - thanks!