# Where to find out if a upgrade is a security upgrade or feature upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I've checked the official Ubuntu site, but I can't find anywhere it says if a release is a security update or just a feature update. For example, if there's a vulnerability in 13.10 that requires an update to 14.04 etc. Is there a place I can check every release to know if I should update because of security or if it's safe to remain at the older version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I start here http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/ and / or with the changelog

See [Seeing apt-get changelogs for to-be-upgraded packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272215/seeing-apt-get-changelogs-for-to-be-upgraded-packages)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As a followup on the same topic, does the security releases actually list the vulnerabilities? I was expecting just to see "There is a security fix" type message and instead I saw some specific reports in that first link. I know some things will give some time before releasing the actual vulnerabilities so you have time to upgrade before announcing the vulnerabilities with your server to everyone.

Comment: I am not sure that there is a specific policy on this one way or another. As such it likely varies by package, update, vulnerability, and maintainer.