# "System restart required"...why? How can I get what triggered this notification to also show details?

Tags: motd

Every so often, I'll SSH into a box with unattended-upgrades and be greeted with "** System restart required ***" with no additional information.

My '/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs' file contains:

```
linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic
linux-base
linux-base
linux-base
```

I don't mind rebooting, but I don't like rebooting without having details of WHY I should reboot in the first place.  Above, I see two packages triggered the message, but there's no explanation beyond that.

Is there a way to get *additional* details about the reason for the reboot to also show up on SSH sign in?

Ideally, I would like to pull in a file that contains something human-readable like, "Package xyz was updated at [date/time].  It needed to modify files a, b, and c but could not because the system blocked/would block the action.  During the next reboot, files a, b, and c will be replaced."  But something not completely human-readable is probably okay too.

Comment: IMO it seems obvious: The kernel got upgraded and it can't replace itself live (at least, not yet).

Comment: Of course it is obvious to you but only because I went digging and looked everything up so that I could demonstrate what I want.  It is NOT obvious as soon as I SSH into the box.  Showing the package list that requires a reboot is also insufficient.  I want to know what date and time that package was updated and a human-readable reason that explains why the package wants the reboot.  If your toaster wanted a reboot, you'd want to know why.  So why not demand as much, if not more, from a highly complex operating system?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot?  Feel free to edit if you think the question needs clarification.

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/846478/why-does-ubuntu-want-to-reboot-so-often-after-installing-updates

Answer (score 36):

Edit: Another, probably relevant or useful [article](https://medium.com/@nobuto_m/knowing-what-services-need-restart-with-needrestart-37419f44ed46).

As you already found out you can find the packages that require a restart in `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`

Now you just need to look in the changelog of the package to find the information you are looking for.

- If you are already on the machine you can find the changelogs in `/usr/share/doc/${package_name}` (example: `zless /usr/share/doc/linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic/changelog.Debian.gz`).
- Debian provides some tools like **`apt-listchanges`** to make this more convenient ([1](https://askubuntu.com/q/272215/40581), [2](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades), [3](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_safeguarding_for_package_problems)).
- Another way to do that would be to use [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

  In your case:

  [image: image showing where to find the link for the changelog on packages.ubuntu.com]

Answer (score 14):

The file ultimately called is `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required` (it's called by `/etc/update-motd.d/98-reboot-required`).

Inside the conditional if statement of one of those files, simply add this:

```
    echo "Packages causing reboot:"
    cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
```

So, for instance, your `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-reboot-required` file would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# helper for update-motd

if [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ]; then
        cat /var/run/reboot-required
        echo "Packages causing reboot:"
        cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
fi
```