# How to find reason for required restart?

Tags: restart

Is there a way to understand WHY exactly my Ubuntu system wants a restart?  I'm getting this message without much additional context in my banner on logging in over SSH:

```
*** System restart required ***
```

Comment: Check your /var/log/apt history. The most common reason (by far) is a new kernel installed by Unattended Upgrades.

Comment: Do either of these refernces answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/258297/should-i-always-restart-the-system-when-i-see-system-restart-required and https://serverfault.com/questions/92932/how-does-ubuntu-keep-track-of-the-system-restart-required-flag-in-motd

Comment: Which release number of Ubuntu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["System restart required"...why? How can I get what triggered this notification to also show details?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661091/system-restart-required-why-how-can-i-get-what-triggered-this-notification)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The packages driving the need to reboot can be listed by running this command

`cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`